# Change background color of diabled input field

Tags: windows-7

Is there a way to change the background color of disabled input fields on Windows 7?

Comment: Just to confirm, you mean native windows apps ?

Comment: It's actually a NAV client, but we are pretty much out of options if it's not getting this information from Windows.